# Why do people Down questions that are asked by misinformed people?

Tags: discussion

It seems that the community doesn't like people who don't know much,  and it really seems to turn down new users. Shouldn't questions only be downvoted if the user's looking to troll or be intentionally negative?
I've also noticed quite a bit of hate answers when this happens?
Why can't we all be polite?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Comment: Maybe we should introduce a BeginnersElectronics.SE where we can migrate all those questions to ;o)

Comment: @jippie  ... or the other way around: leave electronics.stackexchange to beginners and set up eee.stackexchange for no-nonsense pros.

Comment: As a matter of fact a largly similar topic was discussed in chat recently. I believe the consensus was along the lines of: too little effort, exam fraud, easy to Google, too little or no context, applying for a Darwin award, ... etc. The review queues are full of nonsense lately, it is just getting too much for the few who try to keep quality to a reasonable level.

Comment: @NickAlexeev will rep be transferable to eee.se? What will be the meaning of the third 'e'?

Comment: @jippie  Electrical and Electronic Engineering.  There is no reputation transfer on StackExchange (aside from 100 rep association bonus).

Comment: @NickAlexeev so you answered the question about the other way around yourself. ;o)

Comment: @jippie  A good online EE community is one where new users have to send a photo of their oscilloscope to apply for membership.

Comment: @NickAlexeev a two hour delay queue for low rep users would largely solve exam fraud.

Comment: @NickAlexeev haha, if only. I'm (admittedly) no professional by any means, but it was really a turn away when people were calling my schematics 'the worst they've seen', etc. And I looked around to see that this is all too common.

Comment: Without a link to examples we can analyze, this is a pointless discussion.

Comment: @OlinLathrop here are the steps to find more examples than we can discuss. [STEP 1]: go to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions. [STEP 2]: look for a question with negative votes. [STEP 3]: click that question. [STEP 4]: observe the ignorance at work, in both the askers and commenters.

Comment: You are claiming hate and ignorance (your words).  Without specific examples we can all judge as to whether they are really hateful and ignorant, or your perception, or your misunderstanding of how the site works, or whatever, your "question" is just a rant and doesn't belong here.  Voting to close.

Comment: @OlinLathrop and the cycle continues..... if nothing else, use this as an example. it seems to be getting plenty of hate for being ignorant.

Comment: Let me put it another way then.  Nobody is going to take your judgement of hateful and ignorant at face value.  We all want to make up our own minds, which without *specific* examples is impossible.  We are left to conclude, for example, that your schematic really was terrible.

Comment: @OlinLathrop it doesn't matter if it was terrible or not. unconstructive criticism should not be allowed.

Comment: It matters a great deal.  If you dump crap on us, you *should* be kicked in the butt.  If you hand in slop as homework, you probably get lower the grade.  If you hand someone a sloppy resume, you have less chance of getting hired.  Here on SE, you get downvoted and get your question closed.  There are plenty of people who ask good questions here.  We don't need to waste time babying the ones that can't be bothered.  It is less trouble and better for the site in the long run if we simply dispense with them in the most expedient way possible.

Comment: @OlinLathrop and the same thing will happen again and again and again, after schematic after question after answer after answer after answer after question after answer after schematic. again. Ridiculing something that is deemed '*crap*' is not something you should do without stating a reason. This classical conditioning the community seems to be instilling upon the users is ineffective because there are no operands. you guys act as if making a good question is something that is inherently done without reading any guides.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Alright i guess i'll put an ultimatum of this as an answer below, any final thoughts you want me to put in?

Comment: Just check Olin's comment history for examples lol.

Comment: Maybe you could have optional reputation filters on questions .This means that people with low reps dont have to be intimidated and high rep users can be in a high rep environment .If its decided to run another site its my opinion that rep should be transferred.

Comment: I allowed myself to propose a different site. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93532/hardware-hackers?referrer=6H_VWvceg6lVSlXoBzDKSQ2

Answer (score 3):

To quote the tour page:

> Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site
>   for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students,
>   and enthusiasts.

"Professionals, students, and enthusiasts" are not people who have no experience in EE, but still want to do something.  So far as I'm concerned, every post that starts "I program for a living, but have no experience with EE, and I want to ...." is a target for closing/deletion if there's been no effort on research to bring the poster to speed.

I don't care for the hate answers, but I'd prefer to have the signal to noise ratio skewed toward high signal, low noise.

Comment: I've seen posts that at least attempt to do research and they get hated on many a time, not only that, this policy closes off newbies to a wonderful hobby. Not only that, it's thoroughly NOT enforced. I mean, the exact opposite of 'doing research' is what gets the most rep, I mean, of the top monthly questions I would put a heafty ammount of money on the fact that all but 0-3 of them don't cite any research at any point in time besides some "i've been digging" statement they made ambiguously.

Comment: @tuskiomi  this certainly does not close off people from  wonderful hobby, it merely discourages  them from doing it here.  Citing research is not necessary, but being able to understand the discussion you generate is.  It's like when I try to use my limited grasp of foreign language -  My slow strained language use elicits responses that I just can't follow.

Comment: but only the french would call you an idiot for not understanding what a word meant.

Answer (score -1):

To down vote costs reputation so its really easy for high rep users to do and not so easy for low rep .I would call myself middle rep which I should be because I am a consultant and should be no better or no worse than anyone else .I only down vote if something is really wrong .I upvote if I learn something.

Comment: Downvoting questions does not cost rep. Only down voting answers costs the down voter -1